# Trying Exclude 2 days within the year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added my dates with the query so you can so what dates im running. From these dates im trying to exclude 2 days 10/6/2016 and 10/7/2016

```
DECLARE @Startdate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME
SET @Startdate = '10/1/2015'
SET @EndDate = '9/30/2016

SELECT     A.agent_name, COUNT(*) AS CH, (CAST(SUM(reporting_call_matrix.talk_time) / COUNT(reporting_call_matrix.answer_time) AS float) 
                  + CAST(SUM(reporting_call_matrix.hold_time) AS float) / COUNT(reporting_call_matrix.answer_time)) + 
                  CAST(SUM(reporting_call_matrix.work_time) AS float) / COUNT(reporting_call_matrix.answer_time) AS AHT, 
                  answer_agent_id
FROM         reporting_call_matrix  INNER JOIN
                  reporting_agents AS A  ON reporting_call_matrix.answer_agent_id = A.agent_id INNER JOIN
                  reporting_split_info ON reporting_call_matrix.split = reporting_split_info.split 
WHERE     (reporting_call_matrix.answer_agent_id IS NOT NULL) AND (reporting_call_matrix.split IN (9,23)) AND 
                  (reporting_call_matrix.queued_time >= @StartDate) AND (reporting_call_matrix.queued_time < DATEADD(d, 1, @EndDate)) AND 
                  (reporting_call_matrix.answer_time IS NOT NULL) AND 
GROUP BY  A.agent_name,answer_agent_id
```

Comment: Edit your question and tag it with the database you are using.  Also, show the code with the `not between` condition.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are actually trying to do here but I cleaned up this query so it is more legible. I also greatly simplified that nightmarish calculation. You don't have to cast everything to a float, just simply multiple it by 1.0. Also, float is probably not a great choice if you want accuracy because it is an approximate datatype where 1.0 will be numeric which is an exact datatype.

With some aliases and formatting this is so much easier to read.

```
SELECT A.agent_name
    , COUNT(*) AS CH
    , (SUM(rcm.talk_time) + SUM(rcm.hold_time) / COUNT(rcm.answer_time) * 1.0) + (SUM(rcm.work_time) / COUNT(rcm.answer_time) * 1.0) AS AHT
    , answer_agent_id
FROM reporting_call_matrix  rcm 
INNER JOIN reporting_agents AS A  ON rcm.answer_agent_id = A.agent_id 
INNER JOIN reporting_split_info rsi ON rcm.split = rsi.split 
WHERE rcm.answer_agent_id IS NOT NULL
    AND rcm.split IN (9,23)
    AND rcm.queued_time >= @StartDate
    AND rcm.queued_time < DATEADD(day, 1, @EndDate)
    AND rcm.answer_time IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY A.agent_name
    , rcm.answer_agent_id
```

Now, what is the actual question here?

With your recent update I will hazard a guess that queued_time is a date datatype?

Why not simply add one more predicate to your where clause?

```
AND rcm.queued_time not in ('2016-10-06', '2016-10-07')
```

Comment: If this works you should consider marking this as the answer.